# Display subset in recursive algorithm for subset sum

Tags: python, recursion, subset-sum

I have the following algorithm that solves the subset sum problem recursively:

```
def findSubset(alist, targ, i, sumsofar):
    if sumsofar == targ:
        return True
    if i == len(alist):
        return False
    inc = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar+alist[i])
    noninc = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar)
    return inc or noninc
```

The algorithm works fine, but it only gives a boolean answer. So if I call it as so:

```
alist = [4, 6, 21, 29, 37, 50]
findSubset(alist, 76, 0, 0)
>>> True
```

But I would like it to return `[4, 6, 29, 37]`

Here is my attempt at altering the algorithm:

```
def findSubset(alist, targ, i, sumsofar, new):
    if sumsofar == targ:
        return new
    if i == len(alist):
        return []
    inc = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar+alist[i], new.append(alist[i]))
    noninc = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar, new)
    return inc or noninc
```

Where it is used as so:

```
alist = [4, 6, 21, 29, 37, 50]
findSubset(alist, 76, 0, 0, [])
>>>AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What must I do to make it work, is it even possible?

Comment: change `return inc or nonionic` to `return inc if inc else noninc` ?

Comment: @vyscond I still get the same error

Comment: `append()` modifies a list in place and returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My following code works:

```
def findSubset(alist, targ, i, sumsofar, listsofar):
    if sumsofar == targ:
        return True, listsofar
    if i == len(alist):
        return False, listsofar
    inc, inclistsofar = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar+alist[i], listsofar + [alist[i]])
    noninc, noninclistsofar = findSubset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar, listsofar)

    if inc:
        return inc, inclistsofar
    else:
        return noninc, noninclistsofar

alist = [4, 6, 21, 29, 37, 50]
print findSubset(alist, 76, 0, 0, [])
```

list.append() is an in-place operation. It returns None type, but you need to pass a list as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Improvement of the solution by Hengfeng Li. Use default parameters to allow a nicer call without the zeros and the empty list `find_subset(alist, 76)`:

```
def find_subset(alist, targ, i=0, sumsofar=0, listsofar=None):
    if listsofar is None:
        listsofar = []
    if sumsofar == targ:
        return True, listsofar
    if i == len(alist):
        return False, listsofar
    inc, inclistsofar = find_subset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar + alist[i], listsofar + [alist[i]])
    noninc, noninclistsofar = find_subset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar, listsofar)

    if inc:
        return inc, inclistsofar
    else:
        return noninc, noninclistsofar

alist = [4, 6, 21, 29, 37, 50]
print(find_subset(alist, 76))
```

**UPDATE**

Further improvements based on comment from Blckknght:

```
def find_subset(alist, targ, i=0, sumsofar=0, listsofar=None):
    if listsofar is None:
        listsofar = []
    if sumsofar == targ:
        return listsofar
    if i == len(alist):
        return None
    inclistsofar = find_subset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar + alist[i], 
                               listsofar + [alist[i]])
    if inclistsofar:
        return inclistsofar
    else:
        noninclistsofar = find_subset(alist, targ, i+1, sumsofar, listsofar)
        return noninclistsofar

alist = [4, 6, 21, 29, 37, 50]
print(find_subset(alist, 76))
print(find_subset(alist, 100))
print(find_subset(alist, 1000))
print(find_subset(alist, 4))
print(find_subset(alist, 17))
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 29, 37]
[21, 29, 50]
None
[4]
None
```

Comment: A further improvement would be to get rid of the `inc` and `noninc` booleans and return `None` when there's no valid sum. You can probably also greatly improve performance by short circuting and not making the the second recursion if the first one found a result (`inclistsofar = find_subset(...); if inclistsofar is not None: return inclistsofar`).

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the hint. Looks better now.